# How can I display all posts from one custom post type into a select meta box in another?

Tags: wordpress

So, I'm trying to do something a little complicated that's a bit above my current technical level when it comes to WordPress!

I have a custom post type called "**Products**". I want to be able to pull through every "post" from the Products post type into a select meta box on every other post type on the site, standard and custom alike.

Then, I want to be able to use the selection to pull through information onto the page in order to display it to the user.

I have no idea how I'd even *begin* doing this. I can make meta boxes and custom post types, I just don't know how to glue them all together!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have created the same and here is the code which pulls out the post from one `post-type` and displays it in select tag of the post types.

You have to create a meta box and after that alone you need to pull out the posts from another post-type so that it will populate the post names in the select tag of the meta box created as follows.

I have created it for the `destination_category`. you can change the `post_type` and display place in-order to get your codes success.

```
<?php
//Creation of Meta Box for post type "destination_category" (Start)
add_action( 'admin_init', 'my_destination_category' );
//destination_sub_category_admin -  is the required HTML id attribute
//Select Destination Sub Category -  is the text visible in the heading of the meta box section
//display_destination_subcategory_meta_box - is the callback which renders the contents of the meta box
//destination_category - is the name of the custom post type where the meta box will be displayed
// normal - defines the part of the page where the edit screen section should be shown
// high - defines the priority within the context where the boxes should show

function my_destination_category() {
    add_meta_box( 'destination_sub_category_admin','Select Destination Sub Category','display_destination_subcategory_meta_box',     'destination_category', 'normal', 'high');
    function display_destination_subcategory_meta_box( $select_category ) {
    // Retrieve Current Selected Category ID based on the Category Created   
    global $wpdb;
    $selectcat="SELECT * FROM ".$wpdb->prefix."posts WHERE `post_type`='destination_category' AND `post_status`='publish' ORDER BY `ID` DESC";
    $resultant = $wpdb->get_results($selectcat);
    $rescount=count($resultant);
    $category_selected_id = intval( get_post_meta( $select_category->ID, 'destination_category_id', true ) );
    ?>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<?php echo plugins_url('css/metabox.css',__FILE__ ) ?>" />
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td style="width: 150px">Select Category</td>
            <td>
                <select style="width: 100px" name="category_selection" id="meta_box_category" style="float:left; width:50%; !important">
                <?php               
                if($rescount==0)
                {?>
                <option value="null">No Posts have been created</option>
                <?php
                }
                else
                {                
                // Generate all items of drop-down list
                foreach($resultant as $singleresultant)
                {
                ?>
                    <option value="<?php echo $singleresultant->ID; ?>" <?php echo selected( $singleresultant->ID, $category_selected_id ); ?>>
                    <?php echo $singleresultant->post_title; ?>
                    </option>
                    <?php
                    }
                    }
                    ?>
                </select>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    <?php
}
// Registering a Save Post Function
add_action( 'save_post', 'destination_admin_sub_category', 10, 2 );
function destination_admin_sub_category( $select_category_id, $select_category ) {
    // Check post type for movie reviews
    if ( $select_category->post_type == 'destination_category' ) {
        // Store data in post meta table if present in post data
           if ( isset( $_POST['category_selection'] ) && $_POST['category_selection'] != '' ) {
            echo update_post_meta( $select_category_id, 'destination_category_id', $_POST['category_selection'] );
        }
    }
}
}
?>
```

I have provided here with a detailed Explanation of the code so that it will be useful for you to develop the code very easy.

hop so this will help you a lot in order to solve your problems.

Comment: You have to change the `post-type` alone in order to display up in all the posts. If so you find any hindrance in development let me know and i have done it before so that i can explain you very easy of how to develop it. :)

Comment: Thanks for this Naresh! So, if I wanted all of the posts from my **product** post type to show up in all of my other post types apart from the **product** post type, what would I need to change in the code above?

Comment: @LiamRichardson. you first change this and check `destination_category` to your post type `product` and check whether it displays all your created posts under product category so that we can change it afterwards to look up for all posts types..

Comment: Changed it and it works! Perfectly! :) Thanks so much! So now that I can select a post, how can I now access it's information from other post type pages?

Comment: You have to loop through the `add_meta_box()` for all the post types.

Comment: What all post types you have bro.. :)

Comment: So I've managed to add the meta box to all of the post types I need it on and it's working great, thanks for that! Now what I need to do is display the information on my pages :) How do I do that?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/122685/discussion-between-naresh-kumar-p-and-liam-richardson).